# Unable to call CudafyTranslator.Cudafy from Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cudafy.net

I'm trying to use CUDAfy.NET in a web application which will be further called from a web form.

When it tries to initiate a CudafyModule it gives the error as shown in pic below:
[image: Exception]

Code was working perfectly in console application.
Is there anyway to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your web application is unable to talk to the hardware. There is a great deal of abstraction and security in between the IIS and your .NET based assembly. It probably an issue of translation. Depends on how your web application is configured.

There can be several reasons for a process being unable to find the dll.
Try registering the dll in GAC. Or edit your web.config and add a reference to the dll's path
This might resolve the issue.

Comment: Thankz for the help!